# Added file To Public Folder in React - Get 404

Tags: reactjs, azure

I've created a react app using `create-react-app`.  I added a file to the public folder named config.json.  I run this locally and it picks up the file fine and works. However when I deploy it to my azure app service, it does not seem to allow me to navigate to that `config.json` file (it 404's).  I see the file in `wwwrooot` along with other static assets (such as a logo.png).

Why can't I access this config.json file?

[image: filesample]

When I navigate to mysite/logo192.png an image comes up.  When I try mysite/config.json I get a `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` message.

Comment: Check this answer. Its your exact same scenario and error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937016/unable-to-open-json-file-on-server

Comment: @RimazMohommed That worked, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.